# PHP Code Not Displaying Username

Tags: php

My PHP code won't display my user's Username.

It just displays "Hello" and then it's blank. I tried to `print_r($_SESSION)`, but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'] ['user']) && empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
     echo '<a href="/login"><b>Log In</b></a>';
}
else {
     echo "Hello, " . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
     echo '</br></b>';
     echo  '<a href="/login/logout.php"><b>Log Out</b></a>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you're setting the username in the first place? What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` print out? Does it matter that your code references `$_SESSION['user'] ['user']`, `$_SESSION['user']` and `$_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_SESSION)`?

Comment: Hi,print_r($_SESSION) Does The Same Thing

Comment: I Have Been Using this Code and it does work but i cant get it to work with the above one : Hello <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>, secret content!<br />

Comment: @user2925945 `print_r($_SESSION)` will always give you _some_ kind of output. And so far you haven't told us what that is.

Comment: @user2925945 `print_r($_SESSION)` is for _debugging_ the contents of session, not for "making it work."

Answer (score 1):

### Possible Solution

I suspect that the error would be a typo in accessing the array of $_SESSION.

While you are repairing this bug, let's avoid using `htmlspecialchars` function.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
     echo '<a href="/login"><b>Log In</b></a>';
}
else {
     echo "Hello, " . $_SESSION['user'];
     echo '</br></b>';
     echo  '<a href="/login/logout.php"><b>Log Out</b></a>';
}

?>
```

Since you are querying in the `if` for an "user" inside the `$_SESSION`, then the value must be in `$_SESSION['user']`.

---

### How to know what is inside $_SESSION?

If that does not work, THEN you must provide more info. For example, share with us the output of `print_r($_SESSION);`

Like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
     echo '<a href="/login"><b>Log In</b></a>';
}
else {
     echo "This is the value inside of session variable: <br><pre>";
     print_r($_SESSION['user']);
     echo "</pre>";
     echo '</br></b>';
     echo  '<a href="/login/logout.php"><b>Log Out</b></a>';
}

?>
```

The next time you load your webpage in a browser it will not display `Hello`.
It will display what is inside `$_SESSION['user']` !!!!!!!
When you see that provide it to us editing your question or as a response of this answer.

---

### Help! There is nothing inside $_SESSION / The output was blank

Aha my friend. Then you are not setting a value for `$_SESSION['user']` anywhere in your code.

Remember a little bit. Where was the last time you did this:

```
<?php
session_start();
...
$_SESSION['user'] = $someUserValueOrUserName;
```

If your answer is: `OMG I have never done such thing in my life` then you MUST do it in the right place. And that place is where the user LOGINS in your application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user data is stored at `$_SESSION['user']`, since you reference whatever is set at `$_SESSION['user']['user']`. I suspect to retrieve the username you actually want something like `$_SESSION['user']['username']`.